# How to merge a value in a params has in ruby 1.8 and rails 2.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a legacy rails application that has some security issues I am trying to fix.

In particular it is saving from a post using:

```
@user.update_attributes(params[:user])
```

I want to make sure that when saving, one of the attributes is explicitly set in the controller.  There is a variable:

@company

I want to make sure the user.company_id has the value from @company variable before the call to update_attributes.

Comment: `params[:user].merge({company_id: @company.id})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge into params at the controller if you want.

```
user_params = params[:user].merge(:company_id => @company.id)

@user.update_attributes(user_params)
```

The merge will ensure any company_id in the params gets overwritten

Answer (score 1):

just update the user params along with company_id by trying something like this.. it is always advisable to whitelist params by defining pvt method..

```
def user_params
 params.permit(:user)
end
```

`@user.update_attributes(user_params.to_h.merge!({company_id: @company.id}))`

Answer (score 0):

If `company_id` is not present in `params[:user]` then you can set `comapany_id` using `before_filter` in the controller as:

```
    before_filter: set_company_id

private
    def set_company_id
     ##Assuming you have the @user and @company objects before using
     @user.company_id = @company.id
    end
```

so after when you execute:

```
@user.update_attributes(params[:user])
```

@user object will have all the desired attributes saved...